# Open a link of a different origin wont work

Tags: javascript, html, automation, cypress, browser-automation

I'm trying to click on a link to a different domain

I used cy.origin in order to do so but its not working

the link gets clicked and opens but the window is flickering between the page

and a huge text saying :

"YOU ARE VIEWING THIS PAGE IN AN UNAUTHORIZED FRAME WINDOW"

this is the code used to click the link

```
   it('iframe',function(){
    cy.get('#ifmail', { timeout: 20000 }).within(function($iFrame){
      const iFrameContent = $iFrame.contents().find('a').eq(0)
      cy.wrap(iFrameContent).invoke('attr', 'target', '_parent').click()
      cy.origin('www.stage-mycwt.com', () => {
        // below is the actual link
        //https://accounts.stage-mycwt.com/ext/pwdreset2/Reset?adapterId=2AdapterMyCwtWebO
        cy.get('#newPassword').type('pass{enter}')
      })
    })

   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are clicking the link too soon?

```js
cy.origin('www.stage-mycwt.com', () => {
  cy.wrap(iFrameContent).invoke('attr', 'target', '_parent').click()
  cy.get('#newPassword').type('pass{enter}')
  ...
})
```